# JavaScript Array to URLencoded - wthis array in obj

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, urlencode, urldecode

I have array like this

```
{
search: "job", 
keywords: "", 
cat: [12,28,38]
}
```

and I need url string like this

```
?search=job&keywords=&cat%5B%5D=12&cat%5B%5D=28&cat%5B%5D=38
```

for my query in worpdress

please, help

This code

```
var serialize = function(obj, prefix) {
    var str = [],
        p;
    for (p in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            var k = prefix ? prefix + "[" + p + "]" : p,
                v = obj[p];
            str.push((v !== null && typeof v === "object") ?
                serialize(v, k) :
                encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
        }
    }
    return str.join("&");
};
```

and I have this

```
search=job&keywords=&cat%5B0%5D=12&cat%5B1%5D=28&cat%5B2%5D=38
```

but I do not need an index whith "cat"

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please take the time to read the [tour] and especially [ask].  When you have an issue you're expected to show what you've tried so far and what specific problem you are having.

Comment: Did you try `$.param(ob)`?  Your "Array" is not valid javascript, so couldn't test it for you.

Comment: @Xufox - Done, see in my edit

Comment: @freedomn-m - "Your "Array" is not valid javascript, so couldn't test it for you." - edit;  "Did you try $.param(ob)?" - no;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is tagged [jquery], you can use jquery to do this for you, no need to re-invent the wheel:

```js
var x = {
  search: "job",
  keywords: "",
  cat: [12, 28, 38]
};
$("#result").text($.param(x));
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map all key value pairs and check if a value is an array, then add brackets and the values of the array.

```js
var data = { search: "job", keywords: "", cat: ["12", "28", "38"] },
    string = '?' + encodeURI(Object
        .entries(data)
        .map(([k, v]) => Array.isArray(v)
            ? v.map(a => `${k}[]=${a}`).join('&')
            : `${k}=${v}`
        ).join('&'));

console.log(string); // ?search=job&keywords=&cat%5B%5D=12&cat%5B%5D=28&cat%5B%5D=38
```